# Installing Bionic Beaver freezes in the first purple screen

Tags: 18.04

I want to fresh install ubuntu 18.04. When I boot it from USB Drive, and after selecting install ubuntu, it freezes in the first purple screen and after 1 hour waiting, nothing happens. I have currently ubuntu 16.04 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after more than 8 hours, I have realized that my TV is my "main screen".
After disconnecting the HDMI cable, everything started working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a video driver problem. You can follow [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) as answered on this site. Hopefully this solves your problem.

In a nutshell, press the 'e' key when prompted to install Ubuntu. Then simply type `nomodeset` before the words `quiet splash` and see if the install continues (by pressing ctrl+x).

Comment: yes, setting nomodeset solves the problem, but in that case it looks like that os does not have any graphics. things are big and have low contrast and you can not set brightness  and other settings like that ... :'(

Comment: That is a driver problem, what video/graphics card are you using? 'lshw -C video'  will  give some details, then once you know what card you have you can install the appropriate driver. This site will have a lot of answers for that.

Comment: How can I install graphic driver ? I hava downloaded its .run file from amd website, but when I want to install it, it give me error about XServer version.

Comment: What is your "product" (second output line) when you run `lshw -C video`? Also, what driver does it say you are currently using? Usually around the second last line of the same output: `configuration: driver=<drivername> latency=0`.  To install an AMD driver it must support your card, look at this site (https://support.amd.com/en-us/download) for more information and help. Do not download the run file only, download the package and then run the `*.sh` script. Usually these are `install.sh`.  To run it type `./install.sh`.

Comment: `product: RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470]`. in my second last line there is no driver, just `configuration: latency=0`. The AMD Website just gives me one links contains one zip file and inside it, is just one .run file

Comment: Right, so you do not have the driver installed at the moment. I know this can be frustrating but hopefully you can sort it out very soon!

Is it this driver? https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64. If it only provides a run file then what you have done to install it is correct yes. 

If it was that driver and it is still not used (fixing the problem), try and install the amdgpu driver, I am not sure if this is the correct driver but it may solve your problem.

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu`